# How can I use MySQL Greatest() function to return the greatest numeric value?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use MySQL's `GREATEST()` function to return the largest numeric value in a set, even if there's string values in the set?

As far as I know the GREATEST() function returns the greatest *value*, even if it's a string value. For example, the query below returns "N/A" and not "3":

```
SELECT GREATEST(1, 2, 3, "N/A");
--> "N/A"
```

Is there a method or trick where I can get the value "3" instead in the example set above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 3 is returned, but since one of the arguments is a string, the value returned by GREATEST() does not have an integer type.

You can fix it in any of the following ways:

```
SELECT CAST(GREATEST(1, 2, 3, 'N/A') AS SIGNED);

SELECT GREATEST(1, 2, 3, CAST('N/A' AS SIGNED));

SELECT GREATEST(1, 2, 3, 'N/A'+0);
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vCEsRgZt2twf3ja6JWpYrq/2)